# Determine Slow manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The coupled system in two variables $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-xy,\ \ \  \frac{dy}{dt}=-y+x^2-2y^2$$

has the exact [slow manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_manifold) $y=x^2$ on which the evolution is 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-x^3.$$

Could you please anyone explain to me how we got this result?

Comment: Well, if you understood the concept of slow manifold, then you can always try to find it via using power series. So, you are looking for a graph $y = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} a_n x^n$ which is flow-invariant and is tangent to central subspace. Could you proceed further from here?